# Get a message out of an Akka Actor

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I've built an Akka actor that queries an API at regular intervals, like this:

```
  val cancellable =
    system.scheduler.schedule(0 milliseconds,
      5 seconds,
      actor,
      QueryController(1))
```

The Actor, in essence is:

```
object UpdateStatistics {
  /**
   * Query the controller for the given switch Id
   *
   * @param dpId Switch's Id
   */
  case class QueryController(dpId: Int)
  case object Stop

  def props: Props = Props[UpdateStatistics]
}

class UpdateStatistics extends Actor with akka.actor.ActorLogging {
  import UpdateStatistics._

  def receive = {

    case QueryController(id) =>
      import context.dispatcher
      log.info(s"Receiving request to query controller")
      Future { FlowCollector.getSwitchFlows(1) } onComplete {
        f => self ! f.get
      }
    case Stop =>
      log.info(s"Shuting down")
      context stop self
    case json: JValue =>
      log.info("Getting json response, computing features...")
      val features = FeatureExtractor.getFeatures(json)
      log.debug(s"Features: $features")
      sender ! features
    case x =>
      log.warning("Received unknown message: {}", x)
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is get the `json:Jvalue` message out of `UpdateStatistics` actor. Reading the [Akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.16/scala/actors.html#The_Inbox) I thought this may be useful:

```
  implicit val i = inbox()
  i.select() {
     case x => println(s"Valor Devuelto $x")
  }
  println(i receive(2.second))
```

But I do not know how to modify `UpdateStatistics` actor in order to send the result to the inbox above.

Another option I've read in the docs are [event streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.16/scala/event-bus.html#Event_Stream).

But I do not think this is the correct way.

Is there a way of achieving what I want to do? Or do I need to use a second `Actor` to which I send the `JSON` response?

Comment: What exactly to you mean with get the message out of `UpdateStatistic` actor? Who is the recipient? What do you want to do with the data?

Comment: @JorgenGValley I mean get the message to the main thread, outside Akka. For example, in the main app I launch an actor system and schedule the actor to query an api. I want the response of the actor in the main application, not in Akka. I do not know if I explained correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably are looking for the `ask` pattern in AKKA.  This will allow you to return a value to the sender.

```
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.duration._

implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)

val future = actor ? QueryController(1)    
val result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[JValue]

println(result)
```

To make this work, you need to send the response to the original `sender`, rather than `self`.  Also, you should beware the dangers of closing over `sender` in a future when handling messages.

Comment: But this would block the thread, right? `UpdateStatistics` is going to be publishing messages every 5 secons, with your solution I can only get the first response from `UpdateStatistics` Am I right?. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: As written, it would block. Instead, just use `future.onSuccess` to handle the result

Comment: I thought that the actor you asked, had to be the one replying as well, was happily surprised that this wasn't the case. Thanks for this response, made me go back and try and it actually worked responding from another actor which fixed my issue